# Mostrar reporte jasper usando Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jasper-reports

Tengo problemas con un informe JASPER para crear uno.
Estoy usando esta libreria https://github.com/SIMITGROUP/phpjasperxml
Y siga este tutorial sobre cómo incluir la libreria https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-27183-post-170641.html#pid170641

aquí mi archivo javascript

```
 $.ajax({
            data: {
                'c_order_id': 101010,
            },
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>adempiere/c_order_report",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                  window.open('<?php echo base_url() ?>adempiere/c_order_report', '_blank');
            },
  )};
```

Aqui mi controlador.

```
public function c_order_report()
{
    $c_order_id = trim($this->input->post('c_order_id', true));
    $this->load->library('PHPJasperXML');
    $ruta = __DIR__ . '/example.jrxml';
    // echo $ruta;
    // $xml =simplexml_load_file($ruta);
    $PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML("en","TCPDF");
    $PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true;
    $PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter = array('para1'=>'1','para2'=>'2');
    $PHPJasperXML->load_xml_file($ruta);
    $dbdriver="psql";

    $PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray('localhost','adempiere','adempiere','adempiere',$dbdriver);
    $PHPJasperXML->outpage('I'); 
}
```

He intentando de equivocarme en la contraseña de `DB` y me muestra un error, me imagino que funciona la librería.

Aqui un imagen del browser, si agredo el `debug`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué te resulta de `echo is_file($ruta);`? Muéstranos la estructura de archivos de `application/libraries`.

Comment: El servidor parece que tiene un java 1.6, los requerimientos son 1.8